# Como imprimir uma classe em c++?

Tags: c++

Boa tarde, o q estou fazendo de errado na impressão da classe Equipe (nome, numero de membros) na penúltima linha do código? Apresenta o erro: *Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream') and 'void')*

Obrigada!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

class Equipe {
public:
    string nome;
    int numeroDeMembros = 0;
    
    int getMaximoDeTorcedores();
    void imprimir();
};
    int Equipe::getMaximoDeTorcedores(){
        int max = 15+25*numeroDeMembros;
        return max;
    }
    void Equipe::imprimir(){
        cout<<nome<<endl;
        cout<<numeroDeMembros<<endl;
    }
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    
    Equipe *e1 = new Equipe;
    Equipe *e2 = new Equipe;
    
    e1->nome = "Fulano";
    e2->nome = "Beltrano";
    e1->numeroDeMembros = 22;
    e2->numeroDeMembros = 12;
   
    cout<< e1->getMaximoDeTorcedores() <<endl;
    cout<< e2->getMaximoDeTorcedores() <<endl;
    cout<< e1->imprimir()<<endl;
    
    
 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: qual a mensagem de erro?

Comment: Invalid operands to binary expression ('std::__1::ostream' (aka 'basic_ostream<char>') and 'void')

Comment: edita a pergunta e adiciona a mensagem de erro

Answer (score 3):

O método imprimir já faz a impressão, ele não é um *stream* de dados ou mesmo ele sequer retorna algum dado, você deve chamá-lo de forma direta e não em um `cout` que espera um *stream*. A impressão ocorre dentro dele.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Equipe {
public:
    string nome;
    int numeroDeMembros = 0;
    int getMaximoDeTorcedores();
    void imprimir();
};
int Equipe::getMaximoDeTorcedores() {
    return 15 + 25 * numeroDeMembros;
}
void Equipe::imprimir() {
    cout << nome << endl;
    cout << numeroDeMembros << endl;
}
int main(){
    Equipe *e1 = new Equipe;
    Equipe *e2 = new Equipe;
    e1->nome = "Fulano";
    e2->nome = "Beltrano";
    e1->numeroDeMembros = 22;
    e2->numeroDeMembros = 12;
    cout << e1->getMaximoDeTorcedores() << endl;
    cout << e2->getMaximoDeTorcedores() << endl;
    e1->imprimir();
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/mNvT62). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/xhtqxooi-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Function/DirectCall.cpp).

Answer (score 3):

> Como imprimir uma classe em c++

é algo bem genérico.

Vou te mostrar um exemplo comum, e também mostrar porque não funciona o que tentou escrever, muito embora já esteja bem claro na resposta de @Maniero

#### Sua implementação de `imprimir()`

```
void Equipe::imprimir() {
    cout << nome << endl;
    cout << numeroDeMembros << endl;
}
```

`imprimir()` retorna `void` e você escreveu

```
cout << imprimir();
```

- o que é `cout`? `cout` é um fluxo de saída, declarado `ostream`
- o que é `<<`? É o operador de inserção e tem muitas versões para o caso de `cout` que é do tipo `ostream`. Veja:

```
arithmetic types (1)    
ostream& operator<< (bool val);
ostream& operator<< (short val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned short val);
ostream& operator<< (int val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned int val);
ostream& operator<< (long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long val);
ostream& operator<< (long long val);
ostream& operator<< (unsigned long long val);
ostream& operator<< (float val);
ostream& operator<< (double val);
ostream& operator<< (long double val);
ostream& operator<< (void* val);
stream buffers (2)  
ostream& operator<< (streambuf* sb );
manipulators (3)    
ostream& operator<< (ostream& (*pf)(ostream&));
ostream& operator<< (ios& (*pf)(ios&));
ostream& operator<< (ios_base& (*pf)(ios_base&));
```

como está em [CPlusPlus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

Note que não tem nenhuma opção para `void` que é o que sua função `imprimir()` retorna. e por isso o compilador reclamou. E note que tem uma opção para tudo quanto é tipo comum e por isso você pode escrever `cout << "teste"` ou `cout << inteiro` ou qualquer um da lista: **porque está na lista**.

O mais comum pra imprimir uma classe é fazer a mesma coisa que está na lista aqui acima: cria uma versão de `<<` para sua classe `Equipe` e assim o compilador fica satisfeito e você tem mais flexibilidade para controlar a saída, podendo escrever só `cout << e1;` para `e1` uma instância de `Equipe`, claro. Isso se chama *overload* e é só uma redefinição do operador. Você pode redefinir quase todos em C++. O mais comum acho que é mesmo `<<`. E `()` é um caso importante, como vai ver no futuro.
Ao invés de ter por exemplo uma função `soma()` para somar duas `Equipe` você faz isso: redefine o operador `+` e põe o código lá. Ao invés de ter `imprimir()` você redefine `<<`. É um conceito muito útil e faz o código ficar bem compacto e legível, mas no fundo são apenas funções e uma *cola sintática*.

Vou te mostrar um exemplo com seu código, mas pode ver algo documentado mais bonitinho  [em Microsoft docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=vs-2019)

#### um exemplo bem simples com o seu código

**usando *overload* de `<<`**

O que eu alterei? Vai ver que eu criei uma classe Membro e coloquei na equipe um vetor fixo de 10 deles. É só um exemplo afinal. Isso para a nova versão de `imprimir()` mostrar algo assim

```
Equipe 'Fulano' [4] membros  Max 115 torcedores
   1    2                nome
   2    2                dois
   3    2               outro
   4    2                esse

Equipe 'Beltrano' [0] membros  Max 15 torcedores
```

Para um código assim

```
int main(void)
{
    Equipe e1("Fulano");
    Equipe e2("Beltrano");

    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(1, 2, "nome"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(2, 2, "dois"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(3, 2, "outro"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(4, 2, "esse"));

    cout << e1;
    cout << e2;

    return 0;
}
```

Repare que coloquei dois construtores lá para `Equipe`. Entenda que em geral não se escreve como você fez, inicializar valores na definição da classe. Isso só dá problema. Classes tem construtores que existem para isso, e se você coloca um valor aí pode colocar outro diferente no construtor e depois não perceber o problema. E veja que já pode nomear a `Equipe` direto na declaração. Você pode ter um número qualquer de construtores e com parâmetros diferentes. Isso é o tal *polimorfismo*.

**Eis o seu código um pouco alterado**

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
//#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct Membro
{
    int id;
    int idade;
    string nome;

    Membro() : id(0), idade(0), nome("") {};
    Membro(int n, int idade, string nome) :
        id(n), idade(idade), nome(nome) {};
};

class Equipe
{
public:
    string nome;
    int numeroDeMembros;
private:
    Membro      membro[10];

public:
    Equipe() : numeroDeMembros(0) {};
    Equipe(string n) : numeroDeMembros(0), nome(n){};

    int getMaximoDeTorcedores() const;
    int     insereNaEquipe(Membro);

    friend  ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Equipe&);

};  // Equipe{}

int main(void)
{
    Equipe e1("Fulano");
    Equipe e2("Beltrano");

    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(1, 2, "nome"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(2, 2, "dois"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(3, 2, "outro"));
    e1.insereNaEquipe(Membro(4, 2, "esse"));

    cout << e1;
    cout << e2;

    return 0;
}

int Equipe::getMaximoDeTorcedores() const
{
    int max = 15 + 25 * numeroDeMembros;
    return max;
}

int Equipe::insereNaEquipe(Membro um)
{
    if (numeroDeMembros >= 10) return -1;
    membro[numeroDeMembros].nome = um.nome;
    membro[numeroDeMembros].id = um.id;
    membro[numeroDeMembros].idade = um.idade;
    numeroDeMembros += 1;
    return numeroDeMembros;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& saida, const Equipe& E)
{
    saida << "Equipe '" << E.nome <<
        "' [" << E.numeroDeMembros << "] membros " <<
        " Max " << E.getMaximoDeTorcedores() <<
        " torcedores\n";
    for (int m =0; m<E.numeroDeMembros; m+=1)
        saida <<
        setw(4) <<  E.membro[m].id <<
        setw(5) <<  E.membro[m].idade <<
        setw(20) << E.membro[m].nome << endl;
    saida << endl;
    return saida;
};
```

Veja se entende a diferença e pergunte sobre o que achar estranho

#### sobre a função imprimir() de roupa nova

```
    friend  ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Equipe&);
```

Essa é a declaração usual. Em geral se usa esse tal especificador `friend` aí porque sem ele a função não vai ter acesso a variáveis ou métodos da classe marcadas como private. Esse é o efeito e você pode declarar qualquer função assim.

Qual a diferença disso e dela ser simplesmente parte da classe? Pois é: se ela for parte da classe so vai poder ser usada junto com uma instância da classe, e em muitos casos não é prático e por isso vem essa noção meiga de amizade entre classes e métodos.